# Can't get UITextField to populate when using .currency format of NumberFormatter()

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter

I borrowed and modified some code from SO to solve a problem where I was trying to format text that I inputted into my `UITextField`s. If I use the `.decimal` `numberStyle` of `NumberFormatter` it works (adds a comma where I need it) but if I use `.currency` I can't type anything once I run the app. The `UITextField` will not populate.

I've tried playing around with the locale and that doesn't seem to solve anything.

All I want to do is to show the user the "$" sign in front of the number they type as soon as they start typing into the `UITextField`

It's doing it with or without the `digitsOnly` extension I'm using, so that doesn't seem to be causing it.

Relevant code:

```
case annualBill!:
    if isNumeric {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.currencySymbol = "$"

        let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        let numberWithOutCommas = newString.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
        let number = formatter.number(from: numberWithOutCommas)
        if number != nil {
            let formattedString = formatter.string(from: number!)
            textField.text = formattedString
            values.annualBill = Decimal(string: (textField.text?.digitsOnly)!)
            print(values.annualBill ?? "NA")
        } else {
            textField.text = nil
        }

extension String {
    var digitsOnly: String {
        return components(separatedBy: 
    NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined(separator: "")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your text field delegate.

```
var amountString = ""

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if !string.isValidCharacterForCurrency() {
        return false
    }

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

    if string.count > 0 {
        amountString += string
        let decNumber = NSDecimalNumber(string: amountString).multiplying(by: 0.01)
        let newString = "$" + formatter.string(from: decNumber)!
        textField.text = newString

    }
    else {

        amountString = String(amountString.dropLast())
        if amountString.count > 0 {
            let decNumber = NSDecimalNumber(string: amountString).multiplying(by: 0.01)
            let newString = "$" +  formatter.string(from: decNumber)!
            textField.text = newString
        }
        else {
            textField.text = "$0.00"
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

```
extension String {

    func isValidCharacterForCurrency() -> Bool {

        let intValue = Int(self)
        return !(intValue == 0 && self != "0" && self != "")
    }
}
```

Comment: `string` doesn't have a `.count` method because it isn't an array.

Comment: Ah got it, it's `.characters.count` instead. Same with the `dropLast` method. I have it kinda working now. Will update when I get it to 100%. Thanks.

Comment: Got it working with a couple modifications for my specific `switch` statement. Thanks!!

Comment: A couple of observations. First, let’s say the user entered `15` and notices that they meant to enter `25`, so they highlight the `1` and press `2`. You want to replace the `1` with a `2`, not just add the `2` to the end (resulting in `152`). Second, I’d suggest using `Decimal` rather than `NSDecimalNumber`. Third, if you’re going to replace the string with another, you really will want to figure out where the current `UITextPosition` will be in the new string, and update the `position` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your extension and use it with your `newString` and currencyCode such as `USD`, best is to use with the `number with decimal` keyboard so you wont need to check the format beforehand

```
public func toCurrencyFormatter(with currencyCode: String) -> String {
        if NSDecimalNumber(string: self) != NSDecimalNumber.notANumber {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .currency
            formatter.currencyCode = currencyCode
            guard let formattedStr = formatter.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(string: self)) else { return self }
            return formattedStr
        }
        return self
    }
```

Comment: Would I run that directly off the end of my `newString` declaration? Because when I try that I can't input into the `UITextField` at all. If I assign the `textField.text` property with `formattedString?.toCurrencyFormatter(with: "USD")` the first digit will show up formatted properly (i.e. 4 shows up as $4.00) but if I press another digit on the keyboard it zeroes out the field.